# I am having error in sending mail using Codeigniter email library

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Here is my code in Controller

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'kyaw@official-crystal.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'password'
        );

$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

$this->email->from('kyaw@official-crystal.com', 'Kyaw Swar');
$this->email->to('novicewebdeveloper@gmail.com');

$this->email->subject(' CodeIgniter Rocks Socks ');
$this->email->message('Hello World');


if (!$this->email->send())
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
else
    echo 'Your e-mail has been sent!';
```

My problem is that everytime when i send the mail , it show that "The email has been sent"
but it never arrive in my inbox .Much to my suprise is i found  this email in SPAM .. can anybody help me out of this damn problem

Comment: Try to show the print_debugger() even if "it has been sent". That may be an issue with the codeigniter's email class error trapping.

Comment: seems like your smtp provider belongs to spam that is blocked by the email, or you have contents in you're email that looks likes spam. What email provider are you sending to? @iracicot, the library is not the problem, it is sending but he is recieving it on the spam folder, that is the problem

Comment: print_debugger() show no error.

Comment: it is not codding error . it is sever error.thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending headers thats why email is receving in `SPAM`
Try editing this:

```
$config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'kyaw@official-crystal.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'password',
             'mailtype' => 'html',
            'mailpath' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
            'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
             'wordwrap' => TRUE;

        );
```